# Is a good practice to have the Git repository on the execution environment?

Tags: git, moodle

Even if it is a development environment?

I have a development server with a Moodle instance. Currently, I have the following structure:

`/var/www/html/moodle/`<-- The instance of Moodle I'm running on my development server.

`/var/git/` <-- Where I have my moodle.git repository, as same as the git repositories for plugins I develop. For this, I use build tools, among other things, for moving the source code to the Moodle directory in the web server, to make this faster.

The other option would be having something like this:

```
Moodle (execution environment)
├── .git
└── local
    ├── plugin_a
    │   ├── .git
    │   └── source.php
    └── plugin_b
        ├── .git
        └── source.php
```

Where each plugin would have its repository, as same as Moodle.

Which would be the best practice, taking into account that is not a production environment, just a development one?

Comment: Just as a security note, bear in mind that tools exist that can rip (download) your git repo if .git directory is available over http (e.g. accessible on your web server). https://github.com/kost/dvcs-ripper

Comment: @KresimirNesek taking into account that the source code would be open, would you consider this a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which would be the best practice?

The first one: you keep a clear separation between the development environment (the `.git` repo) and the deployment environment (`/var/www/html/moodle/`)

When things go wrong, you don't want to have to shift through git data *in addition* of the files running your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When you speak about "deployment environment", did you take into account that it's a development-dedicated server?

Comment: @Julen yes, but that does not matter: that development-dedicated server still has to serve the app, meaning to execute or run it. And that means you have to keep the two topics separate (dev and deployment). Because in the end, you will have to deploy this app on a production server. If you can do so on a dev server, chances are it will work the same on prod. If you do mix the two on the dev server and do not bother to test the deployment... some nasty surprises can come up when it is time to go to prod.